# Width of div set to either min-width or max-width

Tags: css, max, width, min

I have set a min-width and a max-width to a div.
How can I make it so the div's width is set to max-width if there is enough space and if there isn't enough space the width to be set to min-width?

P.S. using width: 100% kinda works, but I do not want any values inbetween the min and the max. The width should be either min or max and that's it no inbetween.

Comment: Sounds like you want to specify different fixed widths, using media queries, and not use min- and max-width at all ...

Comment: What determines if there is enough space? If it's the window width you could use media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mediaQuery**

Lets assume min-value is 30px and max-value is 100px and that enough-space is 70px
using media query will allow you to define a value if the screen is 70px wide and a different value if the screen is less then that.

for example:

```
@media (max-width: 70px) {
    .myCssClass {width: 30px;}
}
.myCssClass {width: 100px;}
```

in this example the width will "allways" be 100px wide unless the screen is 70px wide or less.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries seem to be the answer.